# iAd crashes on iPad iOS 5.0.1 (only with AppStore version) but runs on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, app-store, iad

My iPhone app (not universal) has iAd on it, and it runs well during my testing on both my iPhone and iPad (the "test advertising" banner is shown). However when I submit it into the AppStore (and get accepted), the app begins to have weird behavior:

- On iPhone it still shows "test advertising". I have removed all test versions of the app before installing from the AppStore, and I thought the store version wouldn't have "test banner"?
- On iPad (5.0.1) it crashes whenever the view with iAd comes up.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you jailbroke your phone, it will show test advertisements when you run real apps.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. What about it's crashes on the iPad (not jailbroken) ?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. I would check your nib/storyboard and make sure you've connected your outlets for iAds on the iPad versions as well. Also, I'm assuming you removeBanner from SuperView each time?

Comment: Yes the outlets are connected, I set the delegate to nil and release the banner in dealloc. I don't remove the banner from its superview though. It works on my iPad during my test (I can see the test banner) so I don't think it has anything to do with iPhone->iPad conversion, unless there are some differences between the AppStore and Debug version regarding iPad/iAd that I don't know of.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe start another question with the iPad Specific iAd code?